# How to change the number of pagination buttons of the DataTables jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

By default, `DataTables` plugin shows 7 paging buttons *(including the ellipses)* like

<kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>...</kbd> <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd>

I would like to be able to change this to a smaller number like

<kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>...</kbd> <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd>

and I can't find this anywhere in the documentation.

I found [this plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/ellipses) but it says that's *deprecated* and that the

> DataTables 1.10 has this ability built in.

but it doesn't show where to change this.

Comment: Would you consider php pagination?

Comment: Data for pagination _is_ done in php, the question was about the interface that's created by the plugin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I finally found it after fiddling with the `DataTable` javascript object and the `DataTables`' source code.

You have to add this line *(either before or after initialization)*:

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 3;
```

**Note** that this will show up like

<kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>...</kbd> <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd>

and not

<kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>...</kbd> <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd>

so be sure to **include** the ellipses in the length number.

**Edit:**

I saw some problems with this solution when advancing through the pages.

I had to rewrite their `_numbers` function like this:

```
function _numbers(page, pages) {
    var
        numbers = [],
        buttons = 5, // added here the number of buttons
        half = Math.floor(buttons / 2);

    if(pages <= buttons) {
        numbers = _range(0, pages);
    } else if(page <= half) {
        numbers = _range(0, buttons - 2);

        numbers.push("ellipsis");
        numbers.push(pages - 1);
    } else if(page >= pages - 1 - half) {
        numbers = _range(pages - (buttons - 2), pages);

        numbers.splice(0, 0, "ellipsis");
        numbers.splice(0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        numbers.push(page); // changed this from _range(page - 1, page + 2);
        numbers.push("ellipsis");
        numbers.push(pages - 1);
        numbers.splice(0, 0, "ellipsis");
        numbers.splice(0, 0, 0);
    }

    numbers.DT_el = "span";

    return numbers;
}
```

And used this to point out `DataTables` to my own function:

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.simple_numbers = function(page, pages) {
    return ["previous", _numbers(page, pages), "next"];
};
```

Also, I had to copy their `_range` function into my `main.js` file.

Comment: How can i use it in my data table function .. Where to apply this function ..Please tell me clearly .. 

Thank you

Comment: I moved away from web development, but the answer is pretty clear, just put it in your main js file.

Comment: Thank you for reply "Iulian Onofrei"  . but this is working only first load data . if we will click on page  no. the pagination reset as same default ..

Comment: @ShrikantBhardwaj, I don't use this anymore so I can't help you.

Comment: Its ok . i had used input type in pagination . And thank you for reply

Comment: how to achieve this in older version dataTable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383805/datatables-change-number-of-pagination-buttons/24383806?noredirect=1#comment74317778_24383806

Answer (score 1):

Combine set up with https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-pagination-without-ellipses/

Add the following after the script loaded

```
<script>
    $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 3;
    $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.full_numbers_no_ellipses = function (e, r) { var a = [], n = $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length, t = Math.floor(n / 2), l = function (e, r) { var a; void 0 === r ? (r = 0, a = e) : (a = r, r = e); for (var n = [], t = r; t < a; t++)n.push(t); return n }; return (a = r <= n ? l(0, r) : e <= t ? l(0, n) : e >= r - 1 - t ? l(r - n, r) : l(e - t, e + t + 1)).DT_el = "span", ["first", "previous", a, "next", "last"] };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear *Leandro Bardelli*. It worked like charm when we provide all the records to datatable in one go. BTW I am using DataTables 1.10.12 version. This solution did not work for me when I fetch records serverside by ajax method of datatable. Could you please suggest me how can we solve this issue when records are fetched by serverside ajax method of datatable? Thanks.

Comment: *Leandro Bardelli* I have added your suggested `<script>.....</script>` code before calling the datatable grid code. It worked for me now in both the situations. 1) Provide all the records to datatable in on go 2) Fetch records by server side ajax rendering method. Thanks a lot dear :)

Answer (score 0):

apparently the ideal minimum for DataTableJS is:

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 5;
```