# dataTables - How to customize the pagination type to show ellipses followed by last page number,

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, pagination

I am using  dataTables 1.9.4 and currently, I use `"sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"`.

For example when there are 10 pages, the pagination displays like <kbd>First</kbd><kbd>Previous</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Next</kbd><kbd>Last</kbd>

I hope to change it into something like :

<kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>...</kbd> <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd>

How can I customize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest version of jQuery datatable library v1.10+ and use "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers" to have pagination in the way you want.

[datatables.net link](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)

Comment: Actually, "sPaginationType" is legacy DataTables syntax (v 1.9 and under).  And "full_numbers" is the default, which is what the OP states is currently occurring.  The OP wants a customization of `full_numbers` which is not available with the standard options.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is found here:

[DataTables change number of pagination buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383805/datatables-change-number-of-pagination-buttons)

The page button layout you've shown is not available with the [standard options](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) for the pagination controls.  It requires a plugin, or customization.  The answer in the link above shows how to write a customization which reduces the default number of paging buttons.