# JQuery Datatables pagination: show 2 previous and 2 next numbers from current page

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

On JQuery [Datatable](https://datatables.net/) I have following pagination style.

`|Previous|1| ....|4|5|6|...|13|Next|`

But I want something like this.

`|Previous|1| ...|3|4|5|6|7|...|13|Next|`

In both cases, 5 is the current page. Is there any way we can achieve that? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from a similar type of StackOverflow question.

[DataTables change number of pagination buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383805/datatables-change-number-of-pagination-buttons)

And the solution for above question is to load [datatable](https://datatables.net/) and add the following line of code as a requirement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 9;
    // number need to be odd number; default is 7
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
var count_of_pages=13;

function set_pages(_page){
   $('#test').empty();
   if(_page==1){
         //start no act
       $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn-noactive">Previous</div>');
   }else{
         //start act
       $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn" onclick="alert(\'start page '+(_page-1)+'\');set_pages('+(_page-1)+');">Previous</div>');
   }
   if(_page>3){
        //1
      $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn" onclick="alert(\'start page '+1+'\');set_pages(1);">'+1+'</div>');
       //.....
      $('#test').append('<div style="display:inline-block;">...</div>');
   }
   for(var i = 1; i < count_of_pages+1; i++) {
         if(((i-2)==_page)||((i-1)==_page)||(i==_page)||((i+1)==_page)||((i+2)==_page)){
            if(i==_page){
             $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn-active">'+i+'</div>');
            }else{
             $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn" onclick="alert(\'start page '+i+'\');set_pages('+i+')">'+i+'</div>');
            }
         }
      }
   if(_page<count_of_pages-3){
        ///....
        $('#test').append('<div style="display:inline-block;">...</div>');
        //count_of_pages
        $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn" onclick="alert(\'start page '+count_of_pages+'\');set_pages('+count_of_pages+');">'+count_of_pages+'</div>');
   }
   if(_page==count_of_pages){
       //end no act
      $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn-noactive">Next</div>');
   }else{
       //end act
      $('#test').append('<div class="white-btn" onclick="alert(\'start page '+(_page+1)+'\');set_pages('+(_page+1)+');">Next</div>');
   }

}

set_pages(6);
```

```css
.white-btn{
   display:inline-block;
   margin:1px;
   padding:2px;
   padding-left:6px;
   padding-right:6px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:gray;
    color:gray;
    border-radius:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .white-btn:hover{
   border-color:black;
   color:black;
  }
  .white-btn-active{
   display:inline-block;
   margin:1px;
   padding:2px;
   padding-left:6px;
   padding-right:6px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:red;
    color:red;
    border-radius:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
  .white-btn-noactive{
   display:inline-block;
   margin:1px;
   padding:2px;
   padding-left:6px;
   padding-right:6px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:gray;
    color:gray;
    border-radius:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="test"></div>


</br></br>
<input type="button" value="set page 5" onclick="set_pages(5);">
<input type="button" value="set page 9" onclick="set_pages(9);">
<input type="button" value="set page 13" onclick="set_pages(13);">
<input type="button" value="set page 1" onclick="set_pages(1);">
<input type="button" value="set page 3" onclick="set_pages(3);">
```

Comment: Really good explanation and example. Appreciated. Many thanks, mate. But I want an easy way to do it with [datatables](https://datatables.net). I have found the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383805/datatables-change-number-of-pagination-buttons . Thanks alot.