# How to hide the last number page in DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

<kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>...</kbd> <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd>

I would like to be able to change this to a smaller number like

<kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>...</kbd>  <kbd>Next</kbd>
r
and I can't find this anywhere in the documentation.

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataTables change number of pagination buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383805/datatables-change-number-of-pagination-buttons)

Comment: it does. Thank sir

Answer (score -1):

please use :  `$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length`

you can have a demo from here ---> [pagination](http://live.datatables.net/sukaxabe/1/edit)